# ASP.Net MVC : Json data getting null at server side action

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-mvc

I am passing json by jquery ajax to controller action but when i debug the action then I notice Section has all null values but when I inspect json there was value.

This is my javascript code where I push data to js array and create json which pass to action.

```
    var Tuner = {};
    Tuner.Tick1 = 'true';
    Tuner.Tick2 = 'false';
    Tuner.Sections = [];

    var Section_LI = {};
    Section_LI.Section='Consensus Model';
    Section_LI.LI = 'Operating Earnings Before Income Taxes';
    Tuner.Sections.push(Section_LI);

    Section_LI = {};
    Section_LI.Section='Consensus Model';
    Section_LI.LI = 'Net Income attributable to common, GAAP';
    Tuner.Sections.push(Section_LI);

    Section_LI = {};
    Section_LI.Section='Consensus Model';
    Section_LI.LI = 'Diluted Shares Outstanding';
    Tuner.Sections.push(Section_LI);

    Section_LI = {};
    Section_LI.Section = 'Test';
    Section_LI.LI = 'Tridip';
    Tuner.Sections.push(Section_LI);

    Section_LI = {};
    Section_LI.Section='Consensus Model';
    Section_LI.LI='Operating EPS';
    Tuner.Sections.push(Section_LI);

    Section_LI = {};
    Section_LI.Section = 'Segment Details';
    Section_LI.LI = 'Limited Partnership Income-Retirement';
    Tuner.Sections.push(Section_LI);

    Section_LI = {};
    Section_LI.Section = 'Segment Details';
    Section_LI.LI = 'Prepayment Fee Income-Retirement';
    Tuner.Sections.push(Section_LI);

    Section_LI = {};
    Section_LI.Section = 'Segment Details';
    Section_LI.LI = 'Gross Investment Income-Retirement';
    Tuner.Sections.push(Section_LI);

    Section_LI = {};
    Section_LI.Section = 'Segment Details';
    Section_LI.LI = 'Investment Expenses-Retirement';
    Tuner.Sections.push(Section_LI);
```

This is the way I am sending data to server side action

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '@Url.Action("Test1", "Home")',
    /*contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',*/

    //data: JSON.stringify({ sdata: Tuner }),
    data: Tuner,

    dataType: 'json',
    /*dataType: 'text',*/
    success: function (response) {
        if (response.success) {
            alert(response.responseText);
        } else {
            // DoSomethingElse()
            alert(response.responseText);
        }
    },
    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
        var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
        alert(err.Message);
    }
});
```

my json

```
{
    "Tick1":"true",
    "Tick2":"false",
    "Sections":
        [
            {"Section":"Consensus Model","LI":"Operating Earnings Before Income Taxes"},
            {"Section":"Consensus Model","LI":"Net Income attributable to common, GAAP"},
            {"Section":"Consensus Model","LI":"Diluted Shares Outstanding"},
            {"Section":"Consensus Model","LI":"Operating EPS"},
            {"Section":"Segment Details","LI":"Limited Partnership Income-Retirement"},
            {"Section":"Segment Details","LI":"Prepayment Fee Income-Retirement"},
            {"Section":"Segment Details","LI":"Gross Investment Income-Retirement"},
            {"Section":"Segment Details","LI":"Investment Expenses-Retirement"}
        ]
}
```

**my action where section data is getting null**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Test1(Tuner sdata)
{
    return Json(new { success = true, responseText = "Your message successfuly sent!" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}

public class Tuner
{
    public string Tick1 { get; set; }
    public string Tick2 { get; set; }
    public List<Sections> Sections { get; set; }    
}

public class Sections
{
    public string Section { get; set; }
    public string LI { get; set; }    
}
```

When I am passing json then whole object is null at server side, using `data: JSON.stringify({ sdata: Tuner }),`

when passing js object instead of json then sections are getting null, using `data: Tuner,`

Where is the problem in my js for which null data is getting pass at server side action? Please tell me how to fix the error.

### EDIT

see the screen shot of server side action where array is getting null
[image]

[image]

### Edit 1

i missed this in ajax `contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',`
after adding this one now everything is fine now.

here is ajax code which properly send data to action and from action i have seen data is coming instead of null

```
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '@Url.Action("Test1", "Home")',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: JSON.stringify({ sdata: Tuner }),
        //data: Tuner,
        dataType: 'json',
        /*dataType: 'text',*/
        success: function (response) {
            if (response.success) {
                alert(response.responseText);
            } else {
                // DoSomethingElse()
                alert(response.responseText);
            }
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
            alert(err.Message);
        }
    });
```

issue closed.

Comment: main problem is when i see the tuner data at asp.net mvc action level then i found Section and LI data is getting null....why it is not getting deserialize at server end?

Comment: When you use `data: Tuner` are Tick1/Tick1 set?

Comment: Did you try changing `public List<Sections> Sections { get; set; }` to `public Sections[] Sections { get; set; }`

Comment: @freedomn-m i have seen js array gets deserialize to List<T>

Comment: @freedomn-m data: Tuner are Tick1/Tick1 set?  yes only array count was right but Section and LI inside array was null at mvc action end

Comment: when i check json before send to server side there was value properly but do not understand why it is not getting deserialize to `List<Sections> Sections`

Comment: Confirming Tick1/Tick2 set in the C# confirms that the correct format is `data:Tuner` and not strangely stringifing it first for a POST.   Then it's a matter of getting the array/list to be bound - the point is that this confirms the js is correct.   So, did you *try* using an array in the C#?

Comment: No i didi not try array in c# like `public Sections[] Sections { get; set; }`

Comment: i convert my `public List<Sections> Sections to public Sections[] Sections { get; set; }` still problem not solved same null is getting. picture added in my post. please see edit section.

Comment: Did it give the `.Sections[9]` with it as a List?  previous comments *implied* (not stated) that `Sections` was null - but you're getting 9 "Sections" which matches your 9 entries.   Can you change the JSON?

Comment: @freedomn-m tell me how json should look like. what change in json tell me.

Comment: The default model binder matches on property names - it *looks like* it should work, so can only make a suggestion:  `{"Tick1":"true","Sections":[{"Sections": {"Section": "Consensus Model", "LI": "Operating Earnings Before Income Taxes"}},{"Sections": {"Section": "Consensus Model", "LI": "Net Income attributable to common, GAAP" }},{"Sections": {"Section": "Consensus Model","LI": "Diluted Shares Outstanding"}}]}` - worth a try I guess?

Comment: @freedomn-m Thanks for your help. issue sorted. i just add this one `contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',` in my jquery ajax and everythings worked like charm. thanks

Comment: @freedomn-m you said default model binder matches on property names. please tell me how can i see what default model binder is working....how to inspect at runtime how default model binder matches on property names.....anyway out there